# ¿Cómo insertar video de VIMEO a una pagina HTML?

Tags: html

Quiero insertar un video con un iframe de vimeo a mi web, pero encontré de dos formas ejemplo:

ejemplo 1:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0&muted=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

ejemplo 2:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?h=9de2897a11?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0&muted=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

La diferencia que veo, es que en donde esta id del video 76979871 en el ejemplo dos tiene - ?h=9de2897a11, si le quito eso funciona de igual manera pero me gustaría saber para que es eso.
Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Da igual.
El  parámetro h debe ser algo interno del propio vimeo, es irrelevante para insertar en una página web.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, entonces no hay ningún problema que lo establezca o no?